# Efficient insertion of named tuple into pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, namedtuple

I have a named tuple called `"rows"` if I print it, it would look as shown below. How do I efficiently (not in for loop) insert this into a pandas data frame so that I can use it to plot graphs. (Number of rows and columns can go more than a thousand sometimes)

```
for row in rows:
    print (row[0], row[1])
```

Output:

```
2016-01-04    00:00:00.000000000
2016-01-04    00:01:00.000000000
2016-01-04    00:02:00.000000000
2016-01-04    00:03:00.000000000
2016-01-04    00:04:00.000000000
2016-01-04    00:05:00.000000000
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(rows)`? Or if this data came from somewhere, perhaps that might be of use.

Comment: @mateen-ulhaq actually `rows` is a result of a `cassandra` database `cql` query.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is long two steps only independently of the length of `rows`:

```
pd.DataFrame([i for i in zip(*rows)])
```

Comment: Thank you, But when I print the dataframe `print(df)` both the answers gives the output `Empty DataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```